# redis data storage with match and range

Tags: php, mongodb, redis

I am trying to use `redis` as a cache layer for my `mongodb` database, my requirement is i have cities collection which consists of all cities of Asia continent and Europe continent and on this data i need to perform search by city name with regex and pagination. I am dumping all cities collection into redis zset. The problem is when i able to do pagination but not able to do search with case sensitive using `zscan and match`. Please help me out is my approach with `redis` is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about right and wrong, but here's how I'd go about this with Redis: The `MATCH` clause does glob-style matching so when you need more robust expression that's a problem. There are three basic approaches you could try in that case:

1. try to normalize your searches to glob-style, if possible, e.g. by always doing lowercase searches (and keeping the data the same)
2. try using `ZRANGEBYLEX`, possibly using the information at http://redis.io/topics/indexes
3. use Lua scripts to implement the regex logic, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945372/3160475

Also note, about pagination with `ZSCAN`, that the `COUNT` switch is only a hint.