# Redis match keys that start with a digit [KEYS]

Tags: regex, redis

Is it possible to get all the keys that start with a digit(e.g. `12.2323.MKSUID`)? the `KEYS` command is supposed to support patterns but what kind of patterns/regex flavour ? I've tried `KEYS \d` with no result.

Comment: [The documentation](https://redis.io/commands/keys) explains it clearly.

Comment: Please read the documentation regarding `KEYS` carefully: > **Warning:** consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care.

Comment: Please avoid using KEYS and opt for SCAN instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting keys that starts with digit.

`KEYS [0-9]*`

Comment: For the sake of future readers: while this answer is 100% correct - KEYS should be avoided in real world situations, and you should use SCAN instead.

Answer (score 4):

The KEYS command supports glob style patterns.  To match keys that start with a digit, you can use the pattern:

```
KEYS [0-9]*
```

As Itamar notes, be careful using KEYS with a pattern match against a live system, it can severely impact performance.

More details and examples can be found in the description of [KEYS](https://redis.io/commands/keys) on [redis.io](https://redis.io)

Answer (score 4):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942541/how-to-get-keys-which-does-not-match-a-particular-pattern-in-redis/35928761#35928761) has some good info. Like the comment suggested, better to use scan:

```
SCAN 0 MATCH "[0-9]*"
```