# Filter Keys + redis + based on condition + node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

Consider my `redis` DB has the following keys available,.

```
"aaa",
"bbb",
"ccc",
"sess:aaa",
"sess:bbb"
```

Now i am using

```
redis.keys('*', function (error, result) {
});
```

to get all keys, but what i need is only `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, by avoiding `sess`prefix.

I i need only `sess`appended data means i can use

```
redis.keys('sess:*', function (error, result) {
    });
```

But how can i retrieve without that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want get all keys except keys with `'sess:*'` prefix? if yes, see
[how to get keys which does not match a particular pattern in redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942541/how-to-get-keys-which-does-not-match-a-particular-pattern-in-redis)