# How to exclude keys with Redis scan_iter()?

Tags: python, redis

With Redis (I'm using Python redis) you can scan keys like this:

```
 keys = redis_client.scan_iter(match='{string}*')
```

However how would I do this if I want to get all keys excluding a certain string? So in this example I would like all keys not starting with '{string}'.

Comment: There are some useful answers in this post, you may take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942541/how-to-get-keys-which-does-not-match-a-particular-pattern-in-redis

Comment: You might need to use Lua script or RedisGears

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://redis.io/commands/scan#the-match-option), the Redis `SCAN` command uses [glob-style syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Syntax). There is no way in that syntax to specify all strings that don't start with a certain string. So you can't do it.

Answer (score -2):

Redis' pattern matching is glob-like so there's no real way to do that. Instead, you can match `*` and use Python's capabilities (e.g. `not str.startswith('s')`)